# Solving a system of exponential-linear equations

Tags: equation-solving

```
eq1 := Abs[-3.533147671810^-6] == 
                A1 Exp[-(-0.53326099689) ((μ1))^2]
eq2 := 7.2716492165  10^-4 == A2 Exp[-(0.53326099689) ((μ2))^2]
eq3 := Abs[-4.0740049497 10^-10] == 
                A3 Exp[-(-8.8857611784 10 ⁻²) ((μ3))^2] 
eq4 := -3.1704480355 10^-6 == 
                2 (-0.53470532215) (μ1) A1 Exp[-(-0.53470532215) ((μ1))^2]
eq5 := -4.6012662532 10^-6 == 
                2 (-0.53470532215) (μ2)  A2 Exp[-(-0.53470532215) ((μ2))^2]
eq6 := -5.0321293376 10^-2 == 
                2 (-0.10263832168) (μ3) A3 Exp[-(-0.10263832168) ((μ3))^2]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: To start, replace `SetDelayed` (`:=`) by `Set` (`=`).

Comment: Propagating typo: When I reformatted the original code by using the { } button, I overlooked that eq3 contained a typo, `(-8.8857611784 10 ⁻.b2)`, which StackExchange then converted to `(-8.8857611784 10 ⁻\.b2)`.  Later, I reformatted the code again by copying the code to Mathematica, which replaced `\[mu]` by `μ`, and then copied it back again.  In the process, the typo further evolved to `(-8.8857611784 10 ⁻²)`.  Finally, @Belisarius interpreted this strange expression as `(-8.885761178410 ^-2)`, which is not unreasonable, although `(-8.8857611784 10 ^-2)` also is possible.

Comment: @bbgodfrey It was my best guess, yes

Comment: Comment, continued.  Andrew Mkolesia, please correct `eq3`.  In addition, look at `eq1`, where `-3.533147671810^-6` perhaps should be `-3.5331476718 10^-6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more an extended comment, although it does answer the question.  Using Belisarius' interpretation of the equations, one might think that

```
Solve[{eq1, eq4}, {A1, m1}]
```

could yield a solution directly, but it returns unevaluated.  However, `Solve` can yield a solution, if provided some hand-holding.

```
solve[{e1_, e2_}, {a_, b_}] := Module[{t1, t2, t3}, t1 = Solve[e1, a]; 
  t2 = Quiet@Solve[e2 /. t1, b]; t3 = Solve[e1 /. t2, a]; Flatten[{t2, t3}]]

solve[{eq1, eq4}, {A1, m1}]
(* {m1 -> 0.83825, A1 -> 2.42902*10^-6} *)
```

For completeness,

```
solve[{eq2, eq5}, {A2, m2}]
(* {m2 -> 0.00591676, A2 -> 0.000727178} *)
solve[{eq3, eq6}, {A3, m3}]
(* {m3 -> 13.9774, A3 -> 3.43099*10^-11} *)
```

Editorial comment: It is a bit disappointing to me that `Solve` cannot do this on its own.

Answer (score 3):

```
eq1 = 3.5331476718 10^-6   == A1                       Exp[-(-0.53326099689) m1^2];
eq2 = 7.2716492165 10^-4   == A2                       Exp[-(0.53326099689) m2^2];
eq3 = 4.0740049497 10^-10  == A3                       Exp[-(-8.885761178410 ^-2) m3^2];
eq4 = -3.1704480355  10^-6 == 2 (-0.53470532215) m1 A1 Exp[-(-0.53470532215) m1^2];
eq5 = -4.6012662532  10^-6 == 2 (-0.53470532215) m2 A2 Exp[-(-0.53470532215) m2^2];
eq6 = -5.0321293376  10^-2 == 2 (-0.10263832168) m3 A3 Exp[-(-0.10263832168) m3^2];
```

Your equations are really pairs. The first two pairs don't present any trouble:

```
FindRoot[{eq1, eq2, eq4, eq5}, {{A1, 1}, {A2, 1}, {m1, 1}, {m2, 1}}]
(* {A1 -> 2.42902*10^-6, A2 -> 0.000727178, m1 -> 0.83825, m2 -> 0.00591676} *)
```

The last pair complains about a null Jacobian, so we use a different strategy:

```
seq3 = Solve[eq3];
sseq36 = eq6 /. seq3;
ns36 = NSolve[sseq36, m3]
(* {{m3 -> 13.9774}} *)
seq3 /. ns36
(* {{{A3 -> 3.43099*10^-11}}} *)
```

The approximation is quite good:

```
{Subtract @@ eq3, Subtract @@ eq6} /. seq3 /. ns36
(* {{{0., 6.93889*10^-17}}} *)
```